# "Proper" way to output variables in a string

Tags: ruby

I have seen quite a few ways to output variables. Which of these ways is "better"?

```
my_name = 'Jeff Hall'
my_height = 74 
puts "Let's talk about %s." % my_name
puts "He's %d inches tall." % my_height
```

vs.

```
puts "Let's talk about #{my_name}."
puts "He's #{my_height} inches tall."
```

Also, what do the `s` and `d` represent after the `%`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer the second way unless I need to format string. For more questions about style check [GitHub Styleguide for Ruby](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby).

About `%s` and `%d`. They are formatters, list of them is on [Ruby Kernel::sprintf doc page](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Answer (score 4):

See the documentation for the [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) method, which references [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) which describes what `%s` and `%d` mean.

String interpolation is nice for simple self-documenting strings. However, using placeholders can make your code shorter, and also gives you formatting power not as simply available with string interpolation:

```
values = { average:12.3, max:15.34734112, min:9.2314311 }
values.each do |name,value|
  puts "%7s: %5.2f" % [ name, value ]
end

#=> average: 12.30
#=>     max: 15.35
#=>     min:  9.23
```

The `printf` codes are geeky as all hell, and they have a [very long history from other languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) (which is why they don't look very Ruby-esque), but they are powerful and terse.

Answer (score 0):

I only recently stumbled upon % called embedding. It seems like it substitutes what you put after the %.

> E.G.

```
name = "harry"
puts "My name is %s" %name
```

The simple answer to %s and %d is %s is for strings, where as %d is for decimals.
 Carrying on with the previous example.

```
age = 35
puts "My name is %s and I am %d years old" %[name, age]
```